# Subtract value multiple times in JS

Tags: javascript

I have two textbox's. Textbox one has the remaining hp that it gets from a variable. Textbox two has a button that when you click it, it runs dmgNPC and subtracts the damage that you enter into the textbox from the hp text box.

The question i have is how do i get JS to subtract from the new value that it shown in the remaining hp textbox?

```js
var hp = 10;

function dmgNPC(hp) {
    var damage = document.getElementById("damage").value;
    var theDMG = hp - damage;

    return document.getElementById("remaining").value = theDMG;
}
```

```html
<label for="damage">Damage to NPC</label>
<input type="text" id="damage">
<button type="button" onclick="dmgNPC(hp);">Enter Damage</button>
<br/>
<label for="remaining">Remaining Health</label>
<input type="text" id="remaining">
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I *think* you want something like this

```js
var hp = 10;

function dmgNPC() {
    var damage = document.getElementById("damage").value;
    hp -= damage;
    document.getElementById("remaining").value = hp;
}
```

```html
<label for="damage">Damage to NPC</label>
<input type="text" id="damage">
<button type="button" onclick="dmgNPC();">Enter Damage</button>
<br/>
<label for="remaining">Remaining Health</label>
<input type="text" id="remaining">
```

Comment: It didn't work at first for some reason, but now it does. Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

Geoffrey let me see if I understand this.  You want to subtract from 10 at the beginning but after that take from the remaining value so you can work your way down to 0 health?  If so here is the JS I wrote for that.

```
var hp = 10;

function dmgNPC(hp) {
    if(document.getElementById("remaining").value){
        var damage = document.getElementById("damage").value;
        var theDMG = document.getElementById("remaining").value - damage;
    }else{
        var damage = document.getElementById("damage").value;
        var theDMG = hp - damage;

    }



    document.getElementById("remaining").value = theDMG;
}
```